# How to implement distributed cache in spark using java

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to implement distributed cache in spark using java. Here I want an Integer variable which is expected to be updated and read at different executor nodes and updated value should be reflected to other executors.

I know that accumulators can be updated on executors but they cannot be read on executors. Only driver program can read their value.

Can anyone please help on  this?

Comment: If you want to use a shared data store, then Spark is the wrong tool for the job. Spark's executors has a share nothing architecture.

Comment: Dikei is right, sounds like you are trying to do something that Spark is not designed for. Maybe look at somethink like Cassandra or HBase for this? Even Kafka might work.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.